# PHP - Session not storing variable values

Tags: php, html

I ' have a very simple PHP script where it takes values of a XML and saves it in $_SESSION. However, when the page is changed and I want to retrieve this values, they are empty. Here is the method that takes the values:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST["LocalitatForm"])) {
recollirDades();
}

function recollirDades(){
    $localitat =  $_REQUEST["localitat"];
    $data = $_REQUEST["data"];
    $min = 0;
    date_format($data, 'Y-m-d');
    $xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("../data/".$localitat.".xml");
    foreach ($xmlDoc->prediccion->dia as $dia){     
        if($dia['fecha'] == $data){
            $min = $dia->temperatura->minima;
            $max = $dia->temperatura->maxima;
        }
    }

    $_SESSION["localitat"] = $localitat;
    $_SESSION["data"] = $data;
    $_SESSION["min"] = $min;
    $_SESSION["max"] = $max;
    header("location: ../views/Temperatura.php");
}
```

And here is the doc ("Temperatura.php") that should show the values:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["localitat"]." ".  $_SESSION["data"] . " " .         
$_SESSION["min"];
$localitat = $_SESSION["localitat"];
$data = $_SESSION["data"];
$min = $_SESSION["min"];
$max = $_SESSION["max"];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Temperatura</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
      <div id='data'>
        Localitat: <?php echo ucfirst($localitat)?><br>
        Data: <?php echo $data ?><br>
        Temperatura mínima: <?php echo $min  ?>ºC<br>
        Temperatura màxima: <?php echo  $max   ?>ºC<br>
    </div>
    <a href='../index.php'><input type='button' value='Tornar a  buscar'>        
   </a>

</body>
</html>
```

In the first file, the values are correct, I' ve checked it with an echo.

Comment: When are you calling `recollirDades()`? Because I can't see where it's being called.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the method call there, is in the beginning of the script

Comment: Don't you see any error in log files?

Comment: And does your if check `isset($_REQUEST["LocalitatForm"])` return true?

Comment: Yes, it seems that Serialitzation of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed. Maybe I should do some kind of conversion after taking the value of the XML node before storing it in $_SESSION?

Comment: Yes, the isset returns true and it goes througth all the method and even takes the right values. However, after doing the header and going to the other page, the values are empty in $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I' ve found the problem. You can't store the value of a XML Node right away in $_SESSION. In this case, I cast it as string. So the code of the method would be like this:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST["LocalitatForm"])) {
recollirDades();
}

function recollirDades(){
$localitat =  $_REQUEST["localitat"];
$data = $_REQUEST["data"];
$min = 0;
date_format($data, 'Y-m-d');
$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file("../data/".$localitat.".xml");
foreach ($xmlDoc->prediccion->dia as $dia){     
    if($dia['fecha'] == $data){
        $min = (string)$dia->temperatura->minima;
        $max = (string)$dia->temperatura->maxima;
    }
}

$_SESSION["localitat"] = $localitat;
$_SESSION["data"] = $data;
$_SESSION["min"] = $min;
$_SESSION["max"] = $max;
header("location: ../views/Temperatura.php");
}
```